# Showing a Wait Message When Submitting Long Javascript Requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, wait

I would like to show an animated gif after a form button is clicked.

**UPDATE**: I found a solution here: http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/fulloverlay.html

I combined that with an animated gif (instead of the login form) to get the effect I wanted.

I used the .show() method in my script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $("#my_submit").click(function(e) { 
        console.log("please wait...");
        $( "#processing_gif" ).show();
        $( "#cover" ).show();
```

In my form I used these divs:

```
        <div id="processing_gif"></div>
        <div id="cover"></div>
```

And I used this CSS:

```
#processing_gif {
   position:fixed; 
   top:0; 
   left:0; 
   z-index:999; 
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   opacity:0.8;
   background: url('/files/animation_processing.gif') center center no-repeat; 
   display:none;
}

#cover{ 
  position:fixed; 
  top:0; left:0; 
  background:rgba(256,256,256,0.9); 
  z-index:1; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  display:none; 
}
```

Here is the full original tutorial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html > <head> <style type="text/css"> .button { width: 150px; padding: 10px; background-color: #FF8C00; box-shadow: -8px 8px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; } #cover{ position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); z-index:5; width:100%; height:100%; display:none; } #loginScreen { height:380px; width:340px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; z-index:10; display:none; background: url(login.png) no-repeat; border:5px solid #cccccc; border-radius:10px; } #loginScreen:target, #loginScreen:target + #cover{ display:block; opacity:2; } .cancel { display:block; position:absolute; top:3px; right:2px; background:rgb(245,245,245); color:black; height:30px; width:35px; font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; } </style> </head> <body> <div align="center"> <br><br><br><br> <a href="#loginScreen" class="button">Click here to Log In</a> </div> <div id="loginScreen"> <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a> </div> <div id="cover" > </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: I would suggest first changing the backend to accept multiple values so the client is not sending an arbitrary number of requests

Comment: @epoch - I don't mind also disabling the button during the wait. But I don't want to change working code. I just want to add a UI clue that it will take a few seconds after the button is clicked.

Comment: Something like this looks similar to what I'm trying to do. But I am not able to get that solution to work so far: 
http://www.west-wind.com/wconnect/weblog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add $("my_image_selector").show() before $.ajax(params) and hide it when "success" or "error" occurs by adding there $("my_image_selector").hide()

Or you can use .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop. [see jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/)

Comment: I would love to use .ajaxStart. I'm looking at the docs. Would you mind giving me a working example based on my code. I'm starting with no experience, so it's hard to figure out the context for some of this... thanks

Comment: I found this one http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=jquery_121. It is not based on your code but the general idea of its use is there. Hope it helps =)

Comment: I tried both methods you suggested and I can't get either one to work. With your first suggestion, where exactly do you think I should add `$("my_image_selector").show()`? I added it right after `$("#add-all-to-cart").click(function(e) {`

Comment: I updated my code based on your answer. Maybe you can see why it isn't working. I can't.

Comment: I tested the first suggestion, it seems to work fine to me. I would check out the console in the browser (f12 in chrome for example). May be you are getting another kind of error :/ ( I ask my self why are you sending the request to a js file (?) )

Comment: You said, "I ask my self why are you sending the request to a js file?" Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: Nothing in particular. I only asked it my self. I see you found a solution. Congrats =) If you want to see a bit of more js I used to visit http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

ah jquery - *sigh*.
You're going to have to tweak this to get the styling/presentation you want, but I'm going to point you in the general direction using plain old JavaScript.

1. Add an image tag with the gif you want to use on the page where you want it

   ```
     < img src='loading.gif'/>
   ```
2. Add an id and "display:none" to the image style to hide it

   ```
   <img id='loadingImg'  style='display:none;' src='loading.gif'/>
   ```
3. get rid of the onclick handler in your submit button tag and instead put code like this below your form

   ```
    <script>
          //listen for click on your button
          document.getElementById('add-all-to-cart').addEventListener('click',
              function(event){
                   //this is the code that runs when the button is clicked
                   //get the button we clicked on
                   var target=event.target||event.srcTarget;
                   //set that button to disabled
                   target.disabled=true;
                   //display the loading image
                   document.getElementById('loadingImg').style.display='block';  
               }

   </script>
   ```

Comment: I think your script is missing the closing `);` but even after adding that I am not seeing the loading.gif image. I added a console.log line after `function(event){` and I don't see the log message either.